# CRC4 INTERLAKEN and ITU lookup table generation

Tags: c++, lookup, crc

I try to geneate CRC4 lookup tables in C++ for the known CRC algorithms **CRC-4/INTERLAKEN** and **CRC-4/ITU**. The CRC definitions are as follows:

```
width=4 poly=0x3 init=0xf refin=false refout=false xorout=0xf check=0xb residue=0x2 name="CRC-4/INTERLAKEN"
width=4 poly=0x3 init=0x0 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0 check=0x7 residue=0x0 name="CRC-4/G-704"
```

I've started adapting the code found from the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051190/882647) to generate lookup table to compare with tables found in the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39091316/882647). If the bit order does not matter for this code, besides polynomial which is the same what else I need to consider? How different would the codes for INTERLAKEN and ITU algorithms be?

The code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void make_crc_table(unsigned long crcTable[])
{
    unsigned long POLYNOMIAL = 0x3;
    unsigned long remainder;
    unsigned char b = 0;
    do
    {
        remainder = b;
        for (unsigned long bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            if (remainder & 1)
                remainder = (remainder >> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
            else
                remainder = (remainder >> 1);
        }
        crcTable[(size_t)b] = remainder;
    } while (0 != ++b);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long crcTable[256];
    make_crc_table(crcTable);
    // Print the CRC table
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "0x";
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << crcTable[i];
        if (i % 16 == 15)
            std::cout << "," << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02,
0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01,
0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03,
0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00,
0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00,
0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03,
0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01,
0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02,
0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01,
0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02,
0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00,
0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03,
0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03,
0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00,
0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02,
0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01,
```

**Original question ends here.**

Update after rcgldr's answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <iomanip>

void make_crc_table(unsigned int crcTable[])
{
    unsigned char POLYNOMIAL = 0xc;
    unsigned char remainder;
    unsigned char b = 0;
    do
    {
        remainder = b;
        for (int bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            if (remainder & 0x80)
                remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
            else
                remainder = (remainder << 1);
        }
        crcTable[(size_t)b] = remainder;
    } while (0 != ++b);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int crcTable[256];
    make_crc_table(crcTable);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "0x";
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << (crcTable[i]);
        if (i % 16 == 15)
            std::cout << "," << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the code:

```
0x00, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x14, 0x30, 0x3c, 0x28, 0x24, 0x60, 0x6c, 0x78, 0x74, 0x50, 0x5c, 0x48, 0x44,
0xc0, 0xcc, 0xd8, 0xd4, 0xf0, 0xfc, 0xe8, 0xe4, 0xa0, 0xac, 0xb8, 0xb4, 0x90, 0x9c, 0x88, 0x84,
0x8c, 0x80, 0x94, 0x98, 0xbc, 0xb0, 0xa4, 0xa8, 0xec, 0xe0, 0xf4, 0xf8, 0xdc, 0xd0, 0xc4, 0xc8,
0x4c, 0x40, 0x54, 0x58, 0x7c, 0x70, 0x64, 0x68, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x34, 0x38, 0x1c, 0x10, 0x04, 0x08,
0x14, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x24, 0x28, 0x3c, 0x30, 0x74, 0x78, 0x6c, 0x60, 0x44, 0x48, 0x5c, 0x50,
0xd4, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xc0, 0xe4, 0xe8, 0xfc, 0xf0, 0xb4, 0xb8, 0xac, 0xa0, 0x84, 0x88, 0x9c, 0x90,
0x98, 0x94, 0x80, 0x8c, 0xa8, 0xa4, 0xb0, 0xbc, 0xf8, 0xf4, 0xe0, 0xec, 0xc8, 0xc4, 0xd0, 0xdc,
0x58, 0x54, 0x40, 0x4c, 0x68, 0x64, 0x70, 0x7c, 0x38, 0x34, 0x20, 0x2c, 0x08, 0x04, 0x10, 0x1c,
0x28, 0x24, 0x30, 0x3c, 0x18, 0x14, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x48, 0x44, 0x50, 0x5c, 0x78, 0x74, 0x60, 0x6c,
0xe8, 0xe4, 0xf0, 0xfc, 0xd8, 0xd4, 0xc0, 0xcc, 0x88, 0x84, 0x90, 0x9c, 0xb8, 0xb4, 0xa0, 0xac,
0xa4, 0xa8, 0xbc, 0xb0, 0x94, 0x98, 0x8c, 0x80, 0xc4, 0xc8, 0xdc, 0xd0, 0xf4, 0xf8, 0xec, 0xe0,
0x64, 0x68, 0x7c, 0x70, 0x54, 0x58, 0x4c, 0x40, 0x04, 0x08, 0x1c, 0x10, 0x34, 0x38, 0x2c, 0x20,
0x3c, 0x30, 0x24, 0x28, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x14, 0x18, 0x5c, 0x50, 0x44, 0x48, 0x6c, 0x60, 0x74, 0x78,
0xfc, 0xf0, 0xe4, 0xe8, 0xcc, 0xc0, 0xd4, 0xd8, 0x9c, 0x90, 0x84, 0x88, 0xac, 0xa0, 0xb4, 0xb8,
0xb0, 0xbc, 0xa8, 0xa4, 0x80, 0x8c, 0x98, 0x94, 0xd0, 0xdc, 0xc8, 0xc4, 0xe0, 0xec, 0xf8, 0xf4,
0x70, 0x7c, 0x68, 0x64, 0x40, 0x4c, 0x58, 0x54, 0x10, 0x1c, 0x08, 0x04, 0x20, 0x2c, 0x38, 0x34,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit order matters. The question's code is using reflected input and output. That means the polynomial should be bit reversed from 0x03 to 0x0c. To confirm this, table entry [0x80] should be 0x0c.

For the Interlaken table, the code should look like:

```
void make_crc_table(unsigned char crcTable[])
{
    unsigned char POLYNOMIAL = 0x30;
    unsigned char remainder;
    unsigned char b = 0;
    do
    {
        remainder = b;
        for (int bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            if (remainder & 0x80)
                remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
            else
                remainder = (remainder << 1);
        }
        crcTable[(size_t)b] = remainder;
    } while (0 != ++b);
}
```

Note that the CRC will be in the upper 4 bits of a byte. When done, the code will need to return (crc>>4)^0x0f.

Comment: Thanks for an the answer @rcgldr. Unfortunately with my hobbyist programming skills I could not figure out how Mark Adler generated the CRC4 tables. Still studying though.

Comment: I have tried with `0x3` for Interlaken and `0xc` for ITU, so far the results does not match with the table from Mark Adler's answer.

Comment: @stardust - Mark Adler's interlaken table indexing assumes that a prior xorout = 0xf has been done to crc, and the table values for crc include an xorout = 0xf. For the initial call to his interlaken crc, use input parameter crc = 0x0 (not 0xf).

Comment: I have updated my question, added the code I am trying.

Comment: @stardust - In my answer, the example code is for Interlaken, but I had called it ITU. My asnwer is fixed now.  For the question's first code, change `POLYNOMIAL = 0x3;` to `POLYNOMIAL = 0xC;`. For the question's second code, change `POLYNOMIAL = 0xc;` to `POLYNOMIAL = 0x30;` .