# Computing CRC16 with reflected / bit reversed input in C

Tags: c, crc, crc16

I want to compute the reflected CRC16 of the CCITT polynomial `0x1021` starting from `0xC6C6` (no XOR at end, also known as CRC16-A on this page https://crccalc.com) in two different ways with (embedded) C.

For the two alternatives, I want to use the polynomial `0x1021` starting with `0xC6C6` as well as the reflected polynomial `0x8408` starting from `0x6363` (= `reflect(0xC6C6)`).

Assume I have a lookup-table for each polynomial:

```
static const UINT16 au16Table1021[256u]
```

and

```
static const UINT16 au16Table8408[256u]
```

and a `reflect` function that reverses the bit order of a byte (e.g. based on 
[In C/C++ what's the simplest way to reverse the order of bits in a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602823/in-c-c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte/2603254#2603254))

From the accepted answer of [How to configure calculation of CRC table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656471/how-to-configure-calculation-of-crc-table) I expected that I would get the same result by reflecting the input, the starting CRC (`wOldCRC = 0xC6C6`), shifting the CRC calculation in the opposed direction and finally reflecting the resulting CRC. However, the second option I tried does not yield the expected result. What am I doing wrong?

Minimal (more or less) working example with incorrect CRC for option 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;

static const uint16_t crcTable1021[256u] = {
  0x0000u, 0x17CEu, 0x0FDFu, 0x1811u, 0x1FBEu, 0x0870u, 0x1061u, 0x07AFu,
  0x1F3Fu, 0x08F1u, 0x10E0u, 0x072Eu, 0x0081u, 0x174Fu, 0x0F5Eu, 0x1890u,
  0x1E3Du, 0x09F3u, 0x11E2u, 0x062Cu, 0x0183u, 0x164Du, 0x0E5Cu, 0x1992u,
  0x0102u, 0x16CCu, 0x0EDDu, 0x1913u, 0x1EBCu, 0x0972u, 0x1163u, 0x06ADu,
  0x1C39u, 0x0BF7u, 0x13E6u, 0x0428u, 0x0387u, 0x1449u, 0x0C58u, 0x1B96u,
  0x0306u, 0x14C8u, 0x0CD9u, 0x1B17u, 0x1CB8u, 0x0B76u, 0x1367u, 0x04A9u,
  0x0204u, 0x15CAu, 0x0DDBu, 0x1A15u, 0x1DBAu, 0x0A74u, 0x1265u, 0x05ABu,
  0x1D3Bu, 0x0AF5u, 0x12E4u, 0x052Au, 0x0285u, 0x154Bu, 0x0D5Au, 0x1A94u,
  0x1831u, 0x0FFFu, 0x17EEu, 0x0020u, 0x078Fu, 0x1041u, 0x0850u, 0x1F9Eu,
  0x070Eu, 0x10C0u, 0x08D1u, 0x1F1Fu, 0x18B0u, 0x0F7Eu, 0x176Fu, 0x00A1u,
  0x060Cu, 0x11C2u, 0x09D3u, 0x1E1Du, 0x19B2u, 0x0E7Cu, 0x166Du, 0x01A3u,
  0x1933u, 0x0EFDu, 0x16ECu, 0x0122u, 0x068Du, 0x1143u, 0x0952u, 0x1E9Cu,
  0x0408u, 0x13C6u, 0x0BD7u, 0x1C19u, 0x1BB6u, 0x0C78u, 0x1469u, 0x03A7u,
  0x1B37u, 0x0CF9u, 0x14E8u, 0x0326u, 0x0489u, 0x1347u, 0x0B56u, 0x1C98u,
  0x1A35u, 0x0DFBu, 0x15EAu, 0x0224u, 0x058Bu, 0x1245u, 0x0A54u, 0x1D9Au,
  0x050Au, 0x12C4u, 0x0AD5u, 0x1D1Bu, 0x1AB4u, 0x0D7Au, 0x156Bu, 0x02A5u,
  0x1021u, 0x07EFu, 0x1FFEu, 0x0830u, 0x0F9Fu, 0x1851u, 0x0040u, 0x178Eu,
  0x0F1Eu, 0x18D0u, 0x00C1u, 0x170Fu, 0x10A0u, 0x076Eu, 0x1F7Fu, 0x08B1u,
  0x0E1Cu, 0x19D2u, 0x01C3u, 0x160Du, 0x11A2u, 0x066Cu, 0x1E7Du, 0x09B3u,
  0x1123u, 0x06EDu, 0x1EFCu, 0x0932u, 0x0E9Du, 0x1953u, 0x0142u, 0x168Cu,
  0x0C18u, 0x1BD6u, 0x03C7u, 0x1409u, 0x13A6u, 0x0468u, 0x1C79u, 0x0BB7u,
  0x1327u, 0x04E9u, 0x1CF8u, 0x0B36u, 0x0C99u, 0x1B57u, 0x0346u, 0x1488u,
  0x1225u, 0x05EBu, 0x1DFAu, 0x0A34u, 0x0D9Bu, 0x1A55u, 0x0244u, 0x158Au,
  0x0D1Au, 0x1AD4u, 0x02C5u, 0x150Bu, 0x12A4u, 0x056Au, 0x1D7Bu, 0x0AB5u,
  0x0810u, 0x1FDEu, 0x07CFu, 0x1001u, 0x17AEu, 0x0060u, 0x1871u, 0x0FBFu,
  0x172Fu, 0x00E1u, 0x18F0u, 0x0F3Eu, 0x0891u, 0x1F5Fu, 0x074Eu, 0x1080u,
  0x162Du, 0x01E3u, 0x19F2u, 0x0E3Cu, 0x0993u, 0x1E5Du, 0x064Cu, 0x1182u,
  0x0912u, 0x1EDCu, 0x06CDu, 0x1103u, 0x16ACu, 0x0162u, 0x1973u, 0x0EBDu,
  0x1429u, 0x03E7u, 0x1BF6u, 0x0C38u, 0x0B97u, 0x1C59u, 0x0448u, 0x1386u,
  0x0B16u, 0x1CD8u, 0x04C9u, 0x1307u, 0x14A8u, 0x0366u, 0x1B77u, 0x0CB9u,
  0x0A14u, 0x1DDAu, 0x05CBu, 0x1205u, 0x15AAu, 0x0264u, 0x1A75u, 0x0DBBu,
  0x152Bu, 0x02E5u, 0x1AF4u, 0x0D3Au, 0x0A95u, 0x1D5Bu, 0x054Au, 0x1284u,
};

static const uint16_t crcTable8408[256u] = {
  0x0000u, 0x1189u, 0x2312u, 0x329Bu, 0x4624u, 0x57ADu, 0x6536u, 0x74BFu,
  0x8C48u, 0x9DC1u, 0xAF5Au, 0xBED3u, 0xCA6Cu, 0xDBE5u, 0xE97Eu, 0xF8F7u,
  0x1081u, 0x0108u, 0x3393u, 0x221Au, 0x56A5u, 0x472Cu, 0x75B7u, 0x643Eu,
  0x9CC9u, 0x8D40u, 0xBFDBu, 0xAE52u, 0xDAEDu, 0xCB64u, 0xF9FFu, 0xE876u,
  0x2102u, 0x308Bu, 0x0210u, 0x1399u, 0x6726u, 0x76AFu, 0x4434u, 0x55BDu,
  0xAD4Au, 0xBCC3u, 0x8E58u, 0x9FD1u, 0xEB6Eu, 0xFAE7u, 0xC87Cu, 0xD9F5u,
  0x3183u, 0x200Au, 0x1291u, 0x0318u, 0x77A7u, 0x662Eu, 0x54B5u, 0x453Cu,
  0xBDCBu, 0xAC42u, 0x9ED9u, 0x8F50u, 0xFBEFu, 0xEA66u, 0xD8FDu, 0xC974u,
  0x4204u, 0x538Du, 0x6116u, 0x709Fu, 0x0420u, 0x15A9u, 0x2732u, 0x36BBu,
  0xCE4Cu, 0xDFC5u, 0xED5Eu, 0xFCD7u, 0x8868u, 0x99E1u, 0xAB7Au, 0xBAF3u,
  0x5285u, 0x430Cu, 0x7197u, 0x601Eu, 0x14A1u, 0x0528u, 0x37B3u, 0x263Au,
  0xDECDu, 0xCF44u, 0xFDDFu, 0xEC56u, 0x98E9u, 0x8960u, 0xBBFBu, 0xAA72u,
  0x6306u, 0x728Fu, 0x4014u, 0x519Du, 0x2522u, 0x34ABu, 0x0630u, 0x17B9u,
  0xEF4Eu, 0xFEC7u, 0xCC5Cu, 0xDDD5u, 0xA96Au, 0xB8E3u, 0x8A78u, 0x9BF1u,
  0x7387u, 0x620Eu, 0x5095u, 0x411Cu, 0x35A3u, 0x242Au, 0x16B1u, 0x0738u,
  0xFFCFu, 0xEE46u, 0xDCDDu, 0xCD54u, 0xB9EBu, 0xA862u, 0x9AF9u, 0x8B70u,
  0x8408u, 0x9581u, 0xA71Au, 0xB693u, 0xC22Cu, 0xD3A5u, 0xE13Eu, 0xF0B7u,
  0x0840u, 0x19C9u, 0x2B52u, 0x3ADBu, 0x4E64u, 0x5FEDu, 0x6D76u, 0x7CFFu,
  0x9489u, 0x8500u, 0xB79Bu, 0xA612u, 0xD2ADu, 0xC324u, 0xF1BFu, 0xE036u,
  0x18C1u, 0x0948u, 0x3BD3u, 0x2A5Au, 0x5EE5u, 0x4F6Cu, 0x7DF7u, 0x6C7Eu,
  0xA50Au, 0xB483u, 0x8618u, 0x9791u, 0xE32Eu, 0xF2A7u, 0xC03Cu, 0xD1B5u,
  0x2942u, 0x38CBu, 0x0A50u, 0x1BD9u, 0x6F66u, 0x7EEFu, 0x4C74u, 0x5DFDu,
  0xB58Bu, 0xA402u, 0x9699u, 0x8710u, 0xF3AFu, 0xE226u, 0xD0BDu, 0xC134u,
  0x39C3u, 0x284Au, 0x1AD1u, 0x0B58u, 0x7FE7u, 0x6E6Eu, 0x5CF5u, 0x4D7Cu,
  0xC60Cu, 0xD785u, 0xE51Eu, 0xF497u, 0x8028u, 0x91A1u, 0xA33Au, 0xB2B3u,
  0x4A44u, 0x5BCDu, 0x6956u, 0x78DFu, 0x0C60u, 0x1DE9u, 0x2F72u, 0x3EFBu,
  0xD68Du, 0xC704u, 0xF59Fu, 0xE416u, 0x90A9u, 0x8120u, 0xB3BBu, 0xA232u,
  0x5AC5u, 0x4B4Cu, 0x79D7u, 0x685Eu, 0x1CE1u, 0x0D68u, 0x3FF3u, 0x2E7Au,
  0xE70Eu, 0xF687u, 0xC41Cu, 0xD595u, 0xA12Au, 0xB0A3u, 0x8238u, 0x93B1u,
  0x6B46u, 0x7ACFu, 0x4854u, 0x59DDu, 0x2D62u, 0x3CEBu, 0x0E70u, 0x1FF9u,
  0xF78Fu, 0xE606u, 0xD49Du, 0xC514u, 0xB1ABu, 0xA022u, 0x92B9u, 0x8330u,
  0x7BC7u, 0x6A4Eu, 0x58D5u, 0x495Cu, 0x3DE3u, 0x2C6Au, 0x1EF1u, 0x0F78u,
};

static uint8_t reverse(uint8_t n) {
   static uint8_t lookup[16] = {
            0x0, 0x8, 0x4, 0xc, 0x2, 0xa, 0x6, 0xe,
            0x1, 0x9, 0x5, 0xd, 0x3, 0xb, 0x7, 0xf, };
   uint8_t result;
   result = lookup[n & 0xF] << 4 | lookup[n>>4];
   return result;
}

static uint16_t reverse16(uint16_t n) {
   return reverse(n & 0xFF) << 8 | reverse(n >> 8);
}

uint16_t Calculate(const uint8_t *message, int nBytes, uint16_t wOldCRC) {
    uint8_t data;
    uint16_t remainder = wOldCRC;
    for (int byte = 0; byte < nBytes; ++byte) {
        data = message[byte] ^ remainder;
        remainder = crcTable8408[data] ^ (remainder >> 8);
    }
    return remainder;
}

uint16_t CalculateInv(const uint8_t *message, int nBytes, uint16_t wOldCRC) {
    uint8_t data;
    uint16_t remainder = wOldCRC; //already reversed in function call
    for (int byte = nBytes; byte > 0; --byte) {
        data = reverse(message[byte-1]) ^ remainder;
        remainder = crcTable1021[data] ^ (remainder << 8);
    }
    return reverse16(remainder);
}

int main(void) {
   uint16_t expected = 0x4167;
   uint8_t pattern[] = "Hello World!";

   uint16_t result = Calculate(pattern, 12, 0x6363);
   printf("CRC option 1: 0x%04x, expected 0x%04x\n", result, expected);

   result = CalculateInv(pattern, 12, 0xC6C6);
   printf("CRC option 2: 0x%04X, expected 0x%04X\n", result, expected);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
CRC option 1: 0x4167, expected 0x4167
CRC option 2: 0x62FD, expected 0x4167
```

Edit: I created the tables by slightly adapting the code from the accepted answer from [How to configure calculation of CRC table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656471/how-to-configure-calculation-of-crc-table) as follows:

```
uint16_t  crcTable[256];
void Init(uint16_t polynomial) {
    uint16_t  remainder;
    for (int dividend = 0; dividend < 256; ++dividend) {
        remainder = dividend;
        for (uint8_t bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit) {
            if (remainder & 1)
                remainder = (remainder >> 1) ^ polynomial;
            else
                remainder = (remainder >> 1);
        }
        crcTable[dividend] = remainder;
    }

    printf("static const uint_t crcTable[256u] = {");
    for (int i = 0; i<32; ++i) {
       printf("\n  ");
       for (int j=0; j<8; ++j) {
          printf("0x%04Xu, ",crcTable[i*8+j]);
       }
    }
    printf("\n};\n");
}
```

Comment: Simplify your test cases for start. Try checking the result for a single zero (`0x00`), then for a single byte with a simple pattern (`0xAA`), and then for an array containing two bytes, again something simple like (`0xAA 0x00`). The answer you linked mentions different ways of shifting and calculating the polynomial depending on whether the input data is reversed or not, so probably the mistake is in a missing shift, or in the way you calculated these crc tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reflected CRC16, only the bits of each byte of a message are reversed, the message itself is not reversed. The other issue is that crcTable1021 needs to be based on a left shifting algorithm, or it can be a copy of crcTable8408 with the index and values reflected. (Comment - the 8408 CRC is a reflected CRC, while the 1021 is normally a non-reflected CRC, but in this case the input and output is being reflected to match the 8408 CRC). Example code that appears to be working:

```
static uint16_t crcTable8408[256u];   // could use table from question
static uint16_t crcTable1021[256u];   // could use table from automationwiki

// ... no changes ... //

uint16_t CalculateInv(const uint8_t *message, int nBytes, uint16_t wOldCRC) {
    uint8_t data;
    uint16_t remainder = wOldCRC; //already reversed in function call
    for (int byte = 0; byte < nBytes; ++byte) {             // fix
        data = reverse(message[byte]) ^ (remainder >> 8);   // fix
        remainder = crcTable1021[data]  ^ (remainder << 8); // fix
    }
    return reverse16(remainder);
}

void InitTables(void) {          // generate tables
    uint16_t  polynomial = 0x8408;
    uint16_t  remainder;
    for (int dividend = 0; dividend < 256; ++dividend) {
        remainder = dividend;
        for (uint8_t bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit) {
            if (remainder & 1)
                remainder = (remainder >> 1) ^ polynomial;
            else
                remainder = (remainder >> 1);
        }
        crcTable8408[dividend] = remainder;
        crcTable1021[reverse(dividend)] = reverse16(remainder);
    }
}

int main(void) {
   uint16_t expected = 0x4167;
   uint8_t pattern[] = "Hello World!";

   InitTables();     // generate tables (or use constant tables)

   uint16_t result = Calculate(pattern, 12, 0x6363);
   printf("CRC option 1: 0x%04X, expected 0x%04x\n", result, expected);

   result = CalculateInv(pattern, 12, 0xC6C6);
   printf("CRC option 2: 0x%04X, expected 0x%04X\n", result, expected);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer to show the method used to generate the tables. It coincides with the tables I get from ticking "show reflected lookup table" on this page: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html for polynomial 0x8408

Comment: Concerning the proposed fix, It did not solve the erroneous CRC, at least not with the current tables. I found a different CRC16-CCITT table here http://automationwiki.com/index.php/CRC-16-CCITT but still no success

Comment: @Aldinger Be very careful when picking these from random internet pages. There are floods of incorrect ones and it's not really standardized, the "CCITT" x.25 document being crap to begin with.

Comment: For test purposes I replaced

`remainder = crcTable1021[data] ^ (remainder << 8);` by `remainder = reverse16(crcTable8408[data]) ^ (remainder << 8);` but again a different CRC

Comment: @Aldinger - I updated my answer, seems to be working now. I deleted my prior comments, I had missed the other issue of the entire message being reversed instead of just the bits of each message byte.

Comment: Great, this produces the same CRC! Yet, somehow I'm not entirely convinced  that we actually compute the CRC on alternative paths. The fix that removes the reverse iteration through the input data makes me feel that we just reflect the input bytes and compare them against a reflected table entry.

I would be happier if the tables would be generated by the same function with different input (`0x1021` or `0x8408`) and if we loop over the input bytes in opposed directions

Comment: @Aldinger - If you wanted to generate a CRC while reversing the iteration through the input data, the input data needs to include the CRC appended to the data. The algorithm is similar to doing long hand division in reverse. Old tape drives that had a read reverse feature did this.

Comment: @Aldinger - The tables can't be generated by the same function. The table for 0x1021 is normally based on a left shift [ remainder = dividend<<8; | 
for (uint8_t bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit) { | if(remainder & 0x8000) | remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ 0x1021; | else | remainder = remainder << 1; } ]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate the code (in C) for any CRC you specify. As it happens, the 16-bit CRC reflected with polynomial 0x1021, initial value 0xc6c6, and final xor 0 is already in the list of standard CRCs. This is the code generated, and it produces 0x4167 for the 12 bytes "Hello, World!":

**crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a.h:**

```
// The _bit, _byte, and _word routines return the CRC of the len bytes at mem,
// applied to the previous CRC value, crc. If mem is NULL, then the other
// arguments are ignored, and the initial CRC, i.e. the CRC of zero bytes, is
// returned. Those routines will all return the same result, differing only in
// speed and code complexity. The _rem routine returns the CRC of the remaining
// bits in the last byte, for when the number of bits in the message is not a
// multiple of eight. The low bits bits of the low byte of val are applied to
// crc. bits must be in 0..8.

#include <stddef.h>

// Compute the CRC a bit at a time.
unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_bit(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len);

// Compute the CRC of the low bits bits in val.
unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_rem(unsigned crc, unsigned val, unsigned bits);

// Compute the CRC a byte at a time.
unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_byte(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len);

// Compute the CRC a word at a time.
unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_word(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len);
```

**crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a.c:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a.h"

// This code assumes that unsigned is 4 bytes.

unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_bit(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0x6363;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}

unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_rem(unsigned crc, unsigned val, unsigned bits) {
    crc &= 0xffff;
    val &= (1U << bits) - 1;
    crc ^= val;
    while (bits--)
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
    return crc;
}

#define table_byte table_word[0]

static unsigned short const table_word[][256] = {
   {0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf, 0x8c48, 0x9dc1,
    0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7, 0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a,
    0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e, 0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64,
    0xf9ff, 0xe876, 0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
    0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5, 0x3183, 0x200a,
    0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c, 0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50,
    0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974, 0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9,
    0x2732, 0x36bb, 0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
    0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a, 0xdecd, 0xcf44,
    0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72, 0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d,
    0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9, 0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3,
    0x8a78, 0x9bf1, 0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
    0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70, 0x8408, 0x9581,
    0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7, 0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb,
    0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff, 0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324,
    0xf1bf, 0xe036, 0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
    0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5, 0x2942, 0x38cb,
    0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd, 0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710,
    0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134, 0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e,
    0x5cf5, 0x4d7c, 0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
    0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb, 0xd68d, 0xc704,
    0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232, 0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e,
    0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a, 0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3,
    0x8238, 0x93b1, 0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
    0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330, 0x7bc7, 0x6a4e,
    0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78},
   {0x0000, 0x19d8, 0x33b0, 0x2a68, 0x6760, 0x7eb8, 0x54d0, 0x4d08, 0xcec0, 0xd718,
    0xfd70, 0xe4a8, 0xa9a0, 0xb078, 0x9a10, 0x83c8, 0x9591, 0x8c49, 0xa621, 0xbff9,
    0xf2f1, 0xeb29, 0xc141, 0xd899, 0x5b51, 0x4289, 0x68e1, 0x7139, 0x3c31, 0x25e9,
    0x0f81, 0x1659, 0x2333, 0x3aeb, 0x1083, 0x095b, 0x4453, 0x5d8b, 0x77e3, 0x6e3b,
    0xedf3, 0xf42b, 0xde43, 0xc79b, 0x8a93, 0x934b, 0xb923, 0xa0fb, 0xb6a2, 0xaf7a,
    0x8512, 0x9cca, 0xd1c2, 0xc81a, 0xe272, 0xfbaa, 0x7862, 0x61ba, 0x4bd2, 0x520a,
    0x1f02, 0x06da, 0x2cb2, 0x356a, 0x4666, 0x5fbe, 0x75d6, 0x6c0e, 0x2106, 0x38de,
    0x12b6, 0x0b6e, 0x88a6, 0x917e, 0xbb16, 0xa2ce, 0xefc6, 0xf61e, 0xdc76, 0xc5ae,
    0xd3f7, 0xca2f, 0xe047, 0xf99f, 0xb497, 0xad4f, 0x8727, 0x9eff, 0x1d37, 0x04ef,
    0x2e87, 0x375f, 0x7a57, 0x638f, 0x49e7, 0x503f, 0x6555, 0x7c8d, 0x56e5, 0x4f3d,
    0x0235, 0x1bed, 0x3185, 0x285d, 0xab95, 0xb24d, 0x9825, 0x81fd, 0xccf5, 0xd52d,
    0xff45, 0xe69d, 0xf0c4, 0xe91c, 0xc374, 0xdaac, 0x97a4, 0x8e7c, 0xa414, 0xbdcc,
    0x3e04, 0x27dc, 0x0db4, 0x146c, 0x5964, 0x40bc, 0x6ad4, 0x730c, 0x8ccc, 0x9514,
    0xbf7c, 0xa6a4, 0xebac, 0xf274, 0xd81c, 0xc1c4, 0x420c, 0x5bd4, 0x71bc, 0x6864,
    0x256c, 0x3cb4, 0x16dc, 0x0f04, 0x195d, 0x0085, 0x2aed, 0x3335, 0x7e3d, 0x67e5,
    0x4d8d, 0x5455, 0xd79d, 0xce45, 0xe42d, 0xfdf5, 0xb0fd, 0xa925, 0x834d, 0x9a95,
    0xafff, 0xb627, 0x9c4f, 0x8597, 0xc89f, 0xd147, 0xfb2f, 0xe2f7, 0x613f, 0x78e7,
    0x528f, 0x4b57, 0x065f, 0x1f87, 0x35ef, 0x2c37, 0x3a6e, 0x23b6, 0x09de, 0x1006,
    0x5d0e, 0x44d6, 0x6ebe, 0x7766, 0xf4ae, 0xed76, 0xc71e, 0xdec6, 0x93ce, 0x8a16,
    0xa07e, 0xb9a6, 0xcaaa, 0xd372, 0xf91a, 0xe0c2, 0xadca, 0xb412, 0x9e7a, 0x87a2,
    0x046a, 0x1db2, 0x37da, 0x2e02, 0x630a, 0x7ad2, 0x50ba, 0x4962, 0x5f3b, 0x46e3,
    0x6c8b, 0x7553, 0x385b, 0x2183, 0x0beb, 0x1233, 0x91fb, 0x8823, 0xa24b, 0xbb93,
    0xf69b, 0xef43, 0xc52b, 0xdcf3, 0xe999, 0xf041, 0xda29, 0xc3f1, 0x8ef9, 0x9721,
    0xbd49, 0xa491, 0x2759, 0x3e81, 0x14e9, 0x0d31, 0x4039, 0x59e1, 0x7389, 0x6a51,
    0x7c08, 0x65d0, 0x4fb8, 0x5660, 0x1b68, 0x02b0, 0x28d8, 0x3100, 0xb2c8, 0xab10,
    0x8178, 0x98a0, 0xd5a8, 0xcc70, 0xe618, 0xffc0},
   {0x0000, 0x5adc, 0xb5b8, 0xef64, 0x6361, 0x39bd, 0xd6d9, 0x8c05, 0xc6c2, 0x9c1e,
    0x737a, 0x29a6, 0xa5a3, 0xff7f, 0x101b, 0x4ac7, 0x8595, 0xdf49, 0x302d, 0x6af1,
    0xe6f4, 0xbc28, 0x534c, 0x0990, 0x4357, 0x198b, 0xf6ef, 0xac33, 0x2036, 0x7aea,
    0x958e, 0xcf52, 0x033b, 0x59e7, 0xb683, 0xec5f, 0x605a, 0x3a86, 0xd5e2, 0x8f3e,
    0xc5f9, 0x9f25, 0x7041, 0x2a9d, 0xa698, 0xfc44, 0x1320, 0x49fc, 0x86ae, 0xdc72,
    0x3316, 0x69ca, 0xe5cf, 0xbf13, 0x5077, 0x0aab, 0x406c, 0x1ab0, 0xf5d4, 0xaf08,
    0x230d, 0x79d1, 0x96b5, 0xcc69, 0x0676, 0x5caa, 0xb3ce, 0xe912, 0x6517, 0x3fcb,
    0xd0af, 0x8a73, 0xc0b4, 0x9a68, 0x750c, 0x2fd0, 0xa3d5, 0xf909, 0x166d, 0x4cb1,
    0x83e3, 0xd93f, 0x365b, 0x6c87, 0xe082, 0xba5e, 0x553a, 0x0fe6, 0x4521, 0x1ffd,
    0xf099, 0xaa45, 0x2640, 0x7c9c, 0x93f8, 0xc924, 0x054d, 0x5f91, 0xb0f5, 0xea29,
    0x662c, 0x3cf0, 0xd394, 0x8948, 0xc38f, 0x9953, 0x7637, 0x2ceb, 0xa0ee, 0xfa32,
    0x1556, 0x4f8a, 0x80d8, 0xda04, 0x3560, 0x6fbc, 0xe3b9, 0xb965, 0x5601, 0x0cdd,
    0x461a, 0x1cc6, 0xf3a2, 0xa97e, 0x257b, 0x7fa7, 0x90c3, 0xca1f, 0x0cec, 0x5630,
    0xb954, 0xe388, 0x6f8d, 0x3551, 0xda35, 0x80e9, 0xca2e, 0x90f2, 0x7f96, 0x254a,
    0xa94f, 0xf393, 0x1cf7, 0x462b, 0x8979, 0xd3a5, 0x3cc1, 0x661d, 0xea18, 0xb0c4,
    0x5fa0, 0x057c, 0x4fbb, 0x1567, 0xfa03, 0xa0df, 0x2cda, 0x7606, 0x9962, 0xc3be,
    0x0fd7, 0x550b, 0xba6f, 0xe0b3, 0x6cb6, 0x366a, 0xd90e, 0x83d2, 0xc915, 0x93c9,
    0x7cad, 0x2671, 0xaa74, 0xf0a8, 0x1fcc, 0x4510, 0x8a42, 0xd09e, 0x3ffa, 0x6526,
    0xe923, 0xb3ff, 0x5c9b, 0x0647, 0x4c80, 0x165c, 0xf938, 0xa3e4, 0x2fe1, 0x753d,
    0x9a59, 0xc085, 0x0a9a, 0x5046, 0xbf22, 0xe5fe, 0x69fb, 0x3327, 0xdc43, 0x869f,
    0xcc58, 0x9684, 0x79e0, 0x233c, 0xaf39, 0xf5e5, 0x1a81, 0x405d, 0x8f0f, 0xd5d3,
    0x3ab7, 0x606b, 0xec6e, 0xb6b2, 0x59d6, 0x030a, 0x49cd, 0x1311, 0xfc75, 0xa6a9,
    0x2aac, 0x7070, 0x9f14, 0xc5c8, 0x09a1, 0x537d, 0xbc19, 0xe6c5, 0x6ac0, 0x301c,
    0xdf78, 0x85a4, 0xcf63, 0x95bf, 0x7adb, 0x2007, 0xac02, 0xf6de, 0x19ba, 0x4366,
    0x8c34, 0xd6e8, 0x398c, 0x6350, 0xef55, 0xb589, 0x5aed, 0x0031, 0x4af6, 0x102a,
    0xff4e, 0xa592, 0x2997, 0x734b, 0x9c2f, 0xc6f3},
   {0x0000, 0x1cbb, 0x3976, 0x25cd, 0x72ec, 0x6e57, 0x4b9a, 0x5721, 0xe5d8, 0xf963,
    0xdcae, 0xc015, 0x9734, 0x8b8f, 0xae42, 0xb2f9, 0xc3a1, 0xdf1a, 0xfad7, 0xe66c,
    0xb14d, 0xadf6, 0x883b, 0x9480, 0x2679, 0x3ac2, 0x1f0f, 0x03b4, 0x5495, 0x482e,
    0x6de3, 0x7158, 0x8f53, 0x93e8, 0xb625, 0xaa9e, 0xfdbf, 0xe104, 0xc4c9, 0xd872,
    0x6a8b, 0x7630, 0x53fd, 0x4f46, 0x1867, 0x04dc, 0x2111, 0x3daa, 0x4cf2, 0x5049,
    0x7584, 0x693f, 0x3e1e, 0x22a5, 0x0768, 0x1bd3, 0xa92a, 0xb591, 0x905c, 0x8ce7,
    0xdbc6, 0xc77d, 0xe2b0, 0xfe0b, 0x16b7, 0x0a0c, 0x2fc1, 0x337a, 0x645b, 0x78e0,
    0x5d2d, 0x4196, 0xf36f, 0xefd4, 0xca19, 0xd6a2, 0x8183, 0x9d38, 0xb8f5, 0xa44e,
    0xd516, 0xc9ad, 0xec60, 0xf0db, 0xa7fa, 0xbb41, 0x9e8c, 0x8237, 0x30ce, 0x2c75,
    0x09b8, 0x1503, 0x4222, 0x5e99, 0x7b54, 0x67ef, 0x99e4, 0x855f, 0xa092, 0xbc29,
    0xeb08, 0xf7b3, 0xd27e, 0xcec5, 0x7c3c, 0x6087, 0x454a, 0x59f1, 0x0ed0, 0x126b,
    0x37a6, 0x2b1d, 0x5a45, 0x46fe, 0x6333, 0x7f88, 0x28a9, 0x3412, 0x11df, 0x0d64,
    0xbf9d, 0xa326, 0x86eb, 0x9a50, 0xcd71, 0xd1ca, 0xf407, 0xe8bc, 0x2d6e, 0x31d5,
    0x1418, 0x08a3, 0x5f82, 0x4339, 0x66f4, 0x7a4f, 0xc8b6, 0xd40d, 0xf1c0, 0xed7b,
    0xba5a, 0xa6e1, 0x832c, 0x9f97, 0xeecf, 0xf274, 0xd7b9, 0xcb02, 0x9c23, 0x8098,
    0xa555, 0xb9ee, 0x0b17, 0x17ac, 0x3261, 0x2eda, 0x79fb, 0x6540, 0x408d, 0x5c36,
    0xa23d, 0xbe86, 0x9b4b, 0x87f0, 0xd0d1, 0xcc6a, 0xe9a7, 0xf51c, 0x47e5, 0x5b5e,
    0x7e93, 0x6228, 0x3509, 0x29b2, 0x0c7f, 0x10c4, 0x619c, 0x7d27, 0x58ea, 0x4451,
    0x1370, 0x0fcb, 0x2a06, 0x36bd, 0x8444, 0x98ff, 0xbd32, 0xa189, 0xf6a8, 0xea13,
    0xcfde, 0xd365, 0x3bd9, 0x2762, 0x02af, 0x1e14, 0x4935, 0x558e, 0x7043, 0x6cf8,
    0xde01, 0xc2ba, 0xe777, 0xfbcc, 0xaced, 0xb056, 0x959b, 0x8920, 0xf878, 0xe4c3,
    0xc10e, 0xddb5, 0x8a94, 0x962f, 0xb3e2, 0xaf59, 0x1da0, 0x011b, 0x24d6, 0x386d,
    0x6f4c, 0x73f7, 0x563a, 0x4a81, 0xb48a, 0xa831, 0x8dfc, 0x9147, 0xc666, 0xdadd,
    0xff10, 0xe3ab, 0x5152, 0x4de9, 0x6824, 0x749f, 0x23be, 0x3f05, 0x1ac8, 0x0673,
    0x772b, 0x6b90, 0x4e5d, 0x52e6, 0x05c7, 0x197c, 0x3cb1, 0x200a, 0x92f3, 0x8e48,
    0xab85, 0xb73e, 0xe01f, 0xfca4, 0xd969, 0xc5d2},
   {0x0000, 0x0b44, 0x1688, 0x1dcc, 0x2d10, 0x2654, 0x3b98, 0x30dc, 0x5a20, 0x5164,
    0x4ca8, 0x47ec, 0x7730, 0x7c74, 0x61b8, 0x6afc, 0xb440, 0xbf04, 0xa2c8, 0xa98c,
    0x9950, 0x9214, 0x8fd8, 0x849c, 0xee60, 0xe524, 0xf8e8, 0xf3ac, 0xc370, 0xc834,
    0xd5f8, 0xdebc, 0x6091, 0x6bd5, 0x7619, 0x7d5d, 0x4d81, 0x46c5, 0x5b09, 0x504d,
    0x3ab1, 0x31f5, 0x2c39, 0x277d, 0x17a1, 0x1ce5, 0x0129, 0x0a6d, 0xd4d1, 0xdf95,
    0xc259, 0xc91d, 0xf9c1, 0xf285, 0xef49, 0xe40d, 0x8ef1, 0x85b5, 0x9879, 0x933d,
    0xa3e1, 0xa8a5, 0xb569, 0xbe2d, 0xc122, 0xca66, 0xd7aa, 0xdcee, 0xec32, 0xe776,
    0xfaba, 0xf1fe, 0x9b02, 0x9046, 0x8d8a, 0x86ce, 0xb612, 0xbd56, 0xa09a, 0xabde,
    0x7562, 0x7e26, 0x63ea, 0x68ae, 0x5872, 0x5336, 0x4efa, 0x45be, 0x2f42, 0x2406,
    0x39ca, 0x328e, 0x0252, 0x0916, 0x14da, 0x1f9e, 0xa1b3, 0xaaf7, 0xb73b, 0xbc7f,
    0x8ca3, 0x87e7, 0x9a2b, 0x916f, 0xfb93, 0xf0d7, 0xed1b, 0xe65f, 0xd683, 0xddc7,
    0xc00b, 0xcb4f, 0x15f3, 0x1eb7, 0x037b, 0x083f, 0x38e3, 0x33a7, 0x2e6b, 0x252f,
    0x4fd3, 0x4497, 0x595b, 0x521f, 0x62c3, 0x6987, 0x744b, 0x7f0f, 0x8a55, 0x8111,
    0x9cdd, 0x9799, 0xa745, 0xac01, 0xb1cd, 0xba89, 0xd075, 0xdb31, 0xc6fd, 0xcdb9,
    0xfd65, 0xf621, 0xebed, 0xe0a9, 0x3e15, 0x3551, 0x289d, 0x23d9, 0x1305, 0x1841,
    0x058d, 0x0ec9, 0x6435, 0x6f71, 0x72bd, 0x79f9, 0x4925, 0x4261, 0x5fad, 0x54e9,
    0xeac4, 0xe180, 0xfc4c, 0xf708, 0xc7d4, 0xcc90, 0xd15c, 0xda18, 0xb0e4, 0xbba0,
    0xa66c, 0xad28, 0x9df4, 0x96b0, 0x8b7c, 0x8038, 0x5e84, 0x55c0, 0x480c, 0x4348,
    0x7394, 0x78d0, 0x651c, 0x6e58, 0x04a4, 0x0fe0, 0x122c, 0x1968, 0x29b4, 0x22f0,
    0x3f3c, 0x3478, 0x4b77, 0x4033, 0x5dff, 0x56bb, 0x6667, 0x6d23, 0x70ef, 0x7bab,
    0x1157, 0x1a13, 0x07df, 0x0c9b, 0x3c47, 0x3703, 0x2acf, 0x218b, 0xff37, 0xf473,
    0xe9bf, 0xe2fb, 0xd227, 0xd963, 0xc4af, 0xcfeb, 0xa517, 0xae53, 0xb39f, 0xb8db,
    0x8807, 0x8343, 0x9e8f, 0x95cb, 0x2be6, 0x20a2, 0x3d6e, 0x362a, 0x06f6, 0x0db2,
    0x107e, 0x1b3a, 0x71c6, 0x7a82, 0x674e, 0x6c0a, 0x5cd6, 0x5792, 0x4a5e, 0x411a,
    0x9fa6, 0x94e2, 0x892e, 0x826a, 0xb2b6, 0xb9f2, 0xa43e, 0xaf7a, 0xc586, 0xcec2,
    0xd30e, 0xd84a, 0xe896, 0xe3d2, 0xfe1e, 0xf55a},
   {0x0000, 0x042b, 0x0856, 0x0c7d, 0x10ac, 0x1487, 0x18fa, 0x1cd1, 0x2158, 0x2573,
    0x290e, 0x2d25, 0x31f4, 0x35df, 0x39a2, 0x3d89, 0x42b0, 0x469b, 0x4ae6, 0x4ecd,
    0x521c, 0x5637, 0x5a4a, 0x5e61, 0x63e8, 0x67c3, 0x6bbe, 0x6f95, 0x7344, 0x776f,
    0x7b12, 0x7f39, 0x8560, 0x814b, 0x8d36, 0x891d, 0x95cc, 0x91e7, 0x9d9a, 0x99b1,
    0xa438, 0xa013, 0xac6e, 0xa845, 0xb494, 0xb0bf, 0xbcc2, 0xb8e9, 0xc7d0, 0xc3fb,
    0xcf86, 0xcbad, 0xd77c, 0xd357, 0xdf2a, 0xdb01, 0xe688, 0xe2a3, 0xeede, 0xeaf5,
    0xf624, 0xf20f, 0xfe72, 0xfa59, 0x02d1, 0x06fa, 0x0a87, 0x0eac, 0x127d, 0x1656,
    0x1a2b, 0x1e00, 0x2389, 0x27a2, 0x2bdf, 0x2ff4, 0x3325, 0x370e, 0x3b73, 0x3f58,
    0x4061, 0x444a, 0x4837, 0x4c1c, 0x50cd, 0x54e6, 0x589b, 0x5cb0, 0x6139, 0x6512,
    0x696f, 0x6d44, 0x7195, 0x75be, 0x79c3, 0x7de8, 0x87b1, 0x839a, 0x8fe7, 0x8bcc,
    0x971d, 0x9336, 0x9f4b, 0x9b60, 0xa6e9, 0xa2c2, 0xaebf, 0xaa94, 0xb645, 0xb26e,
    0xbe13, 0xba38, 0xc501, 0xc12a, 0xcd57, 0xc97c, 0xd5ad, 0xd186, 0xddfb, 0xd9d0,
    0xe459, 0xe072, 0xec0f, 0xe824, 0xf4f5, 0xf0de, 0xfca3, 0xf888, 0x05a2, 0x0189,
    0x0df4, 0x09df, 0x150e, 0x1125, 0x1d58, 0x1973, 0x24fa, 0x20d1, 0x2cac, 0x2887,
    0x3456, 0x307d, 0x3c00, 0x382b, 0x4712, 0x4339, 0x4f44, 0x4b6f, 0x57be, 0x5395,
    0x5fe8, 0x5bc3, 0x664a, 0x6261, 0x6e1c, 0x6a37, 0x76e6, 0x72cd, 0x7eb0, 0x7a9b,
    0x80c2, 0x84e9, 0x8894, 0x8cbf, 0x906e, 0x9445, 0x9838, 0x9c13, 0xa19a, 0xa5b1,
    0xa9cc, 0xade7, 0xb136, 0xb51d, 0xb960, 0xbd4b, 0xc272, 0xc659, 0xca24, 0xce0f,
    0xd2de, 0xd6f5, 0xda88, 0xdea3, 0xe32a, 0xe701, 0xeb7c, 0xef57, 0xf386, 0xf7ad,
    0xfbd0, 0xfffb, 0x0773, 0x0358, 0x0f25, 0x0b0e, 0x17df, 0x13f4, 0x1f89, 0x1ba2,
    0x262b, 0x2200, 0x2e7d, 0x2a56, 0x3687, 0x32ac, 0x3ed1, 0x3afa, 0x45c3, 0x41e8,
    0x4d95, 0x49be, 0x556f, 0x5144, 0x5d39, 0x5912, 0x649b, 0x60b0, 0x6ccd, 0x68e6,
    0x7437, 0x701c, 0x7c61, 0x784a, 0x8213, 0x8638, 0x8a45, 0x8e6e, 0x92bf, 0x9694,
    0x9ae9, 0x9ec2, 0xa34b, 0xa760, 0xab1d, 0xaf36, 0xb3e7, 0xb7cc, 0xbbb1, 0xbf9a,
    0xc0a3, 0xc488, 0xc8f5, 0xccde, 0xd00f, 0xd424, 0xd859, 0xdc72, 0xe1fb, 0xe5d0,
    0xe9ad, 0xed86, 0xf157, 0xf57c, 0xf901, 0xfd2a},
   {0x0000, 0x9fd5, 0x37bb, 0xa86e, 0x6f76, 0xf0a3, 0x58cd, 0xc718, 0xdeec, 0x4139,
    0xe957, 0x7682, 0xb19a, 0x2e4f, 0x8621, 0x19f4, 0xb5c9, 0x2a1c, 0x8272, 0x1da7,
    0xdabf, 0x456a, 0xed04, 0x72d1, 0x6b25, 0xf4f0, 0x5c9e, 0xc34b, 0x0453, 0x9b86,
    0x33e8, 0xac3d, 0x6383, 0xfc56, 0x5438, 0xcbed, 0x0cf5, 0x9320, 0x3b4e, 0xa49b,
    0xbd6f, 0x22ba, 0x8ad4, 0x1501, 0xd219, 0x4dcc, 0xe5a2, 0x7a77, 0xd64a, 0x499f,
    0xe1f1, 0x7e24, 0xb93c, 0x26e9, 0x8e87, 0x1152, 0x08a6, 0x9773, 0x3f1d, 0xa0c8,
    0x67d0, 0xf805, 0x506b, 0xcfbe, 0xc706, 0x58d3, 0xf0bd, 0x6f68, 0xa870, 0x37a5,
    0x9fcb, 0x001e, 0x19ea, 0x863f, 0x2e51, 0xb184, 0x769c, 0xe949, 0x4127, 0xdef2,
    0x72cf, 0xed1a, 0x4574, 0xdaa1, 0x1db9, 0x826c, 0x2a02, 0xb5d7, 0xac23, 0x33f6,
    0x9b98, 0x044d, 0xc355, 0x5c80, 0xf4ee, 0x6b3b, 0xa485, 0x3b50, 0x933e, 0x0ceb,
    0xcbf3, 0x5426, 0xfc48, 0x639d, 0x7a69, 0xe5bc, 0x4dd2, 0xd207, 0x151f, 0x8aca,
    0x22a4, 0xbd71, 0x114c, 0x8e99, 0x26f7, 0xb922, 0x7e3a, 0xe1ef, 0x4981, 0xd654,
    0xcfa0, 0x5075, 0xf81b, 0x67ce, 0xa0d6, 0x3f03, 0x976d, 0x08b8, 0x861d, 0x19c8,
    0xb1a6, 0x2e73, 0xe96b, 0x76be, 0xded0, 0x4105, 0x58f1, 0xc724, 0x6f4a, 0xf09f,
    0x3787, 0xa852, 0x003c, 0x9fe9, 0x33d4, 0xac01, 0x046f, 0x9bba, 0x5ca2, 0xc377,
    0x6b19, 0xf4cc, 0xed38, 0x72ed, 0xda83, 0x4556, 0x824e, 0x1d9b, 0xb5f5, 0x2a20,
    0xe59e, 0x7a4b, 0xd225, 0x4df0, 0x8ae8, 0x153d, 0xbd53, 0x2286, 0x3b72, 0xa4a7,
    0x0cc9, 0x931c, 0x5404, 0xcbd1, 0x63bf, 0xfc6a, 0x5057, 0xcf82, 0x67ec, 0xf839,
    0x3f21, 0xa0f4, 0x089a, 0x974f, 0x8ebb, 0x116e, 0xb900, 0x26d5, 0xe1cd, 0x7e18,
    0xd676, 0x49a3, 0x411b, 0xdece, 0x76a0, 0xe975, 0x2e6d, 0xb1b8, 0x19d6, 0x8603,
    0x9ff7, 0x0022, 0xa84c, 0x3799, 0xf081, 0x6f54, 0xc73a, 0x58ef, 0xf4d2, 0x6b07,
    0xc369, 0x5cbc, 0x9ba4, 0x0471, 0xac1f, 0x33ca, 0x2a3e, 0xb5eb, 0x1d85, 0x8250,
    0x4548, 0xda9d, 0x72f3, 0xed26, 0x2298, 0xbd4d, 0x1523, 0x8af6, 0x4dee, 0xd23b,
    0x7a55, 0xe580, 0xfc74, 0x63a1, 0xcbcf, 0x541a, 0x9302, 0x0cd7, 0xa4b9, 0x3b6c,
    0x9751, 0x0884, 0xa0ea, 0x3f3f, 0xf827, 0x67f2, 0xcf9c, 0x5049, 0x49bd, 0xd668,
    0x7e06, 0xe1d3, 0x26cb, 0xb91e, 0x1170, 0x8ea5},
   {0x0000, 0x81bf, 0x0b6f, 0x8ad0, 0x16de, 0x9761, 0x1db1, 0x9c0e, 0x2dbc, 0xac03,
    0x26d3, 0xa76c, 0x3b62, 0xbadd, 0x300d, 0xb1b2, 0x5b78, 0xdac7, 0x5017, 0xd1a8,
    0x4da6, 0xcc19, 0x46c9, 0xc776, 0x76c4, 0xf77b, 0x7dab, 0xfc14, 0x601a, 0xe1a5,
    0x6b75, 0xeaca, 0xb6f0, 0x374f, 0xbd9f, 0x3c20, 0xa02e, 0x2191, 0xab41, 0x2afe,
    0x9b4c, 0x1af3, 0x9023, 0x119c, 0x8d92, 0x0c2d, 0x86fd, 0x0742, 0xed88, 0x6c37,
    0xe6e7, 0x6758, 0xfb56, 0x7ae9, 0xf039, 0x7186, 0xc034, 0x418b, 0xcb5b, 0x4ae4,
    0xd6ea, 0x5755, 0xdd85, 0x5c3a, 0x65f1, 0xe44e, 0x6e9e, 0xef21, 0x732f, 0xf290,
    0x7840, 0xf9ff, 0x484d, 0xc9f2, 0x4322, 0xc29d, 0x5e93, 0xdf2c, 0x55fc, 0xd443,
    0x3e89, 0xbf36, 0x35e6, 0xb459, 0x2857, 0xa9e8, 0x2338, 0xa287, 0x1335, 0x928a,
    0x185a, 0x99e5, 0x05eb, 0x8454, 0x0e84, 0x8f3b, 0xd301, 0x52be, 0xd86e, 0x59d1,
    0xc5df, 0x4460, 0xceb0, 0x4f0f, 0xfebd, 0x7f02, 0xf5d2, 0x746d, 0xe863, 0x69dc,
    0xe30c, 0x62b3, 0x8879, 0x09c6, 0x8316, 0x02a9, 0x9ea7, 0x1f18, 0x95c8, 0x1477,
    0xa5c5, 0x247a, 0xaeaa, 0x2f15, 0xb31b, 0x32a4, 0xb874, 0x39cb, 0xcbe2, 0x4a5d,
    0xc08d, 0x4132, 0xdd3c, 0x5c83, 0xd653, 0x57ec, 0xe65e, 0x67e1, 0xed31, 0x6c8e,
    0xf080, 0x713f, 0xfbef, 0x7a50, 0x909a, 0x1125, 0x9bf5, 0x1a4a, 0x8644, 0x07fb,
    0x8d2b, 0x0c94, 0xbd26, 0x3c99, 0xb649, 0x37f6, 0xabf8, 0x2a47, 0xa097, 0x2128,
    0x7d12, 0xfcad, 0x767d, 0xf7c2, 0x6bcc, 0xea73, 0x60a3, 0xe11c, 0x50ae, 0xd111,
    0x5bc1, 0xda7e, 0x4670, 0xc7cf, 0x4d1f, 0xcca0, 0x266a, 0xa7d5, 0x2d05, 0xacba,
    0x30b4, 0xb10b, 0x3bdb, 0xba64, 0x0bd6, 0x8a69, 0x00b9, 0x8106, 0x1d08, 0x9cb7,
    0x1667, 0x97d8, 0xae13, 0x2fac, 0xa57c, 0x24c3, 0xb8cd, 0x3972, 0xb3a2, 0x321d,
    0x83af, 0x0210, 0x88c0, 0x097f, 0x9571, 0x14ce, 0x9e1e, 0x1fa1, 0xf56b, 0x74d4,
    0xfe04, 0x7fbb, 0xe3b5, 0x620a, 0xe8da, 0x6965, 0xd8d7, 0x5968, 0xd3b8, 0x5207,
    0xce09, 0x4fb6, 0xc566, 0x44d9, 0x18e3, 0x995c, 0x138c, 0x9233, 0x0e3d, 0x8f82,
    0x0552, 0x84ed, 0x355f, 0xb4e0, 0x3e30, 0xbf8f, 0x2381, 0xa23e, 0x28ee, 0xa951,
    0x439b, 0xc224, 0x48f4, 0xc94b, 0x5545, 0xd4fa, 0x5e2a, 0xdf95, 0x6e27, 0xef98,
    0x6548, 0xe4f7, 0x78f9, 0xf946, 0x7396, 0xf229}
};

unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_byte(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0x6363;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}

// This code assumes that integers are stored little-endian.

unsigned crc16iso_iec_14443_3_a_word(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0x6363;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len && ((ptrdiff_t)data & 0x7)) {
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
        len--;
    }
    if (len >= 8) {
        do {
            uintmax_t word = crc ^ *(uintmax_t const *)data;
            crc = table_word[7][word & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[6][(word >> 8) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[5][(word >> 16) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[4][(word >> 24) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[3][(word >> 32) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[2][(word >> 40) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[1][(word >> 48) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[0][word >> 56];
            data += 8;
            len -= 8;
        } while (len >= 8);
    }
    while (len--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it's shows an optimization for handling 8 bytes at a time without requiring usage of carryless multiply (PCLMULQDQ) methods (500+ lines of assembly code for an optimized version). The OP wanted to be able to double reflect the CRC code to produce the same result, but this example could be used to generate non-reflected code, and then modified to double reflect.